# How to create a custom service worker in angular

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular15

I don't care about PWA stuff, I just want to manage state across tabs from a singular place to avoid race conditions and unnecessary api calls. So, I don't need the stuff angular creates with ng generate service-worker. Also, I would like to use typescript.